# Relating Temp / Size / Time to Mortality Rates from Catch and Release Fishing

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, biostatistics, research-design, capture-mark-recapture

I am conducting a fish catch and release mortality study and have hit a wall with the statistics portion of my report and could use a nudge in the right direction. I am trying to relate a few variables to overall mortality rates in fish. Things like the how long it took to catch the fish, the temperature of the water, size, reflex impairment, etc. I am currently in the pilot stage and only have a sample size of 13 with that increasing to 150 upon the next field season.

I have attached the data I have gathered thus far. I would be greatly appreciated for some tips on how to go about analyzing this data and making reasonable comparisons between the different variables effect on mortality. Obviously with a sample size this small I don't predict any significant relationships but regardless, if this was your data set how would you go about analyzing it? My ultimate goal is to define relationships between these variables and their overall affect on mortality rates.

Data:
[image: C&R Data]

```
Temp   Length    Weight Total Time RAMP  Hook Location   Status
28.78    975      6.44      227      2         8L        DEAD
31.44    890      4.16      210      2        1G/1T      DEAD
32.22    951      5.97      145      1        8R/3G      DEAD
28.18    958      6.44      253      2        2F/5L      ALIVE
27.67    983      7.12      234      1        2G/2T      ALIVE
27.8     806      3.06      189      2         2L        ALIVE
24.41    1089     8.92      173      2         11L       ALIVE
```

Comment: Thanks. We also prefer the data itself to be easily readble! so people can simple cut&paste into their preferred program! Please do so ...

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen i think i have it edited to your liking. Any thoughts on the best approaches for analyzing this data set? There will be hundreds of observation on the long term of these variables between different groups/populations

Comment: Thanks again, it's better now. But, I dont understand all your variable names --- what is RAMP? And what the strange values under Hook location mean? Total time? Is that total time from catch ntil release? In seconds? ... People will need such informatin for an answer!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen if you open the image from imgur that is all there i just had to condense it for it to be in text. But yes, total time is the moment you hook the fish until it is released in seconds. RAMP stands for reflex action mortality predictor, and is a predictor score for likelihood of mortality based off of reflex responses upon release (0 being no response). Hook location value correspond to a grid matrix of a fishes mouth. So 8L = 8th quadrant left side of mouth. 1G = 1st quadrant Gills, etc.

Comment: If you want to model the probability of death as a function of covariates, look into logistic regression LR (search this site.) But, a problem: 150 observations is few for LR so try to get a larger sample